# Grub: preferred video interface at boottime

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, multiple-monitors, hdmi

My HDTV is connected through HDMI. My desktop through DVI. At boottime grub displays the bootmenu ( where I can choose for Windows or Linux) only on the HDMI interface. Since my TV is off during most of the time this is undesirable. I would very much like the grub menu to appear on the DVI interface.
I am using on board video. My motherboard is a MSI FM2-A75MA-E35.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Hans

Answer (score 0):

This is not an option you can select in GRUB, it's a BIOS option.

In your BIOS, you should be able to select a default video output for boot up.

Comment: This was my first thought too. But then I found there is no such option in the BIOS menu. So perhaps it is not configurable at all. But if it is it must be in the bootloader. In my case that is grub since I am using a dual boot systeem (Lubuntu and Windows 7 32 bit).

To be sure about this I mailed the manufacturer of my motherboard (MSI). Still in the process of expecting an answer. If it arrives and it is useful I will post it on this forum.

Anyway thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: I have got an answer from MSI. here it is: The bios of the A75-series does not allow prioritizing the display outputs.
We heard future Intel platform are going to support this, but for AMD this does not seem to be possible with the current technology. But now the funny part:Somehow I did the trick: the bootloader output is on both monitors. I fiddled a bit with system -> screensetting under Lubuntu and voila!